# Questions regarding getchar and putchar in C (K&R)

Tags: c, getchar, kernighan-and-ritchie, putchar

so I'm learning C by following the book, 'The C Programming Language 2nd Edition' by Dennis Ritchie and Brian Kernighan. In section `1.5.1 File Copying`, the following program is shown:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

/* copy input to output; 1st version */
main()
{
    int c;
    
    c = getchar()
    while (c != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

and I had a few questions here.

1. Why is the variable `c` declared as an `int`? Because it's a `getchar()` function shouldn't it be of type `char`?
2. What is the difference between `putchar` and `printf`?
3. I don't get what is the `EOF` mentioned in the condition of the `while` loop

Thanks!

Comment: The beginners assumption that a "character" is `char` (likewise that a "number" is an `int`). Almost every C library function that involves taking a character as an argument, or returning a character uses `int`. In the case of `getchar()` we need to distinguish the data `0xFF` from the flag `EOF` (-1). That flag isn't data but a signal that there is no more input (End Of File). Also, if you look at `sizeof 'a'` you'll find it isn't `1` but the same as `sizeof (int)`.

Comment: Ah right, that variable is declared as an `int` so that it can be checked whether it's equal to `EOF` or not, and `EOF` is -1

Comment: Yes, and the function declaration is **`int`** `getchar(void);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Why is the variable `c` declared as an `int`? Because it's a `getchar()` function shouldn't it be of type `char`?

`getchar` cannot return just  `char` because it needs to return either a character (if the operation succeeded) or `EOF` (if the operation failed).

Therefore `getchar` returns an `int`. If the operation successfully read a character, it returns the character as an `unsigned char` value. (This is one reason that operations with characters ought to prefer to use the `unsigned char` type. Avoid using `char`.) If the operation did not read a character, either because there are no more characters in the input stream or because an error occurred, then `getchar` returns `EOF`. `EOF` has some negative value, so it is always different from an `unsigned char` value.

If you assign the result of `getchar` to a `char`, the `int` value will be converted to a `char`. In a typical C implementation, there are 257 possible return values from `getchar`—256 character values and one `EOF` value, but a `char` has only 256 possible values. Therefore, the conversion will map at least two different values to the same thing, usually `EOF` and some other character. Then it is impossible to tell those two things apart from the `char` value. You need to use an `int` to preserve the original `getchar` return value.

> 2. What is the difference between `putchar` and `printf`?

`putchar` sends a single character to the standard output stream.

`printf` performs formatting operations and sends the results to the standard output stream. Even in the simplest case where `printf` is given only a format string with no arguments to be converted, it is still given a string, not a single character.

> 3. I don't get what is the `EOF` mentioned in the condition of the `while` loop

`EOF` stands for “End Of File,” but it is return by `getchar` if either the end of the stream is reached or if an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

- `char` is just a 7-bit number. The computer encodes those numbers to a character using whatever character encoding your computer uses(mostly ASCII). Most C libraries function even used `int` to do something related to handling characters. In this case, `getchar()` returns an `int`, so using `int` in this case is intentional.
- `putchar()` just print one character base on the input value, while `printf()` can do anything you like.
- The `EOF` ("end of file") character is received when there is no more input.`while (c != EOF)` will exit the loop if we receive `EOF`

Comment: So, I assume `EOF` is something like `ctrl+c`?

Comment: On Linux is Ctrl-D and Windows is Ctrl-Z. But Ctrl-C is handled differently. It ends the program, not the input.

Comment: It is important to realize that the `EOF` value in C has nothing to do with the character typed to indicate end-of-file at the terminal. The character typed (usually ctrl-d on Unix-like systems) is never returned. Instead, the terminal device driver notices it and causes the `read()` system call to return zero bytes read, which indicates end-of-file to the higher levels. The C library again intercepts this end-of-file indication and makes `getchar()` return `EOF` (which is usually -1).

Comment: `char` is not limited to a seven-bit number, in most C implementations.